# How to integrate Apache Airflow with slack?

Tags: airflow, slack

could someone please give me step by step manual on how to connect Apache Airflow to Slack workspace.
I created webhook to my channel and what should I do with it next ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Create a Slack Token from
  https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens
- Use the `SlackAPIPostOperator` Operator in your DAG as below

```py
SlackAPIPostOperator(
      task_id='failure',
      token='YOUR_TOKEN',
      text=text_message,
      channel=SLACK_CHANNEL,
      username=SLACK_USER)
```

The above is the simplest way you can use Airflow to send messages to Slack.

However, if you want to configure Airflow to send messages to Slack on task failures, create a function and add `on_failure_callback` to your tasks with the name of the created slack function. An example is below:

```py
def slack_failed_task(contextDictionary, **kwargs):  
       failed_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
         task_id='slack_failed',
         channel="#datalabs",
         token="...",
         text = ':red_circle: DAG Failed',
         owner = '_owner',)
         return failed_alert.execute()


task_with_failed_slack_alerts = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task0',
    python_callable=<file to execute>,
    on_failure_callback=slack_failed_task,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

**Using SlackWebHook** (Works only for Airflow >= 1.10.0):
If you want to use `SlackWebHook` use `SlackWebhookOperator` in a similar manner:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/slack_webhook_operator.py#L25

Comment: Is there any way to connect via webhook ?

Comment: If you want to use Webhook, use `SlackWebhookOperator` check https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1801baefe44f361010c23e6ec4ee8b8569eab82d/airflow/contrib/operators/slack_webhook_operator.py#L25

Comment: @kaxil I had to change the last line of slack_failed_task() to be return failed_alert.execute(), without the parenthesis no slack message was being sent. Otherwise it was pretty good answer and helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Try the new **SlackWebhookOperator** which is there in Airflow version>=1.10.0

```py
from airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator import SlackWebhookOperator

slack_msg = "Hi Wssup?"

slack_test =  SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_test',
        http_conn_id='slack_connection',
        webhook_token='/1234/abcd',
        message=slack_msg,
        channel='#airflow_updates',
        username='airflow_'+os.environ['ENVIRONMENT'],
        icon_emoji=None,
        link_names=False,
        dag=dag)
```

Note: Make sure you have `slack_connection` added in your Airflow connections as

```
host=https://hooks.slack.com/services/
```

Comment: is there any way to not use the connection here? I'm using the AWS Secrets Manager to store the `webhook_token` and I don't want to also manage another airflow connection for it!

Answer (score 5):

The full example with `SlackWebhookOperator` usage as in @kaxil answer:

```
def slack_failed_task(task_name):
  failed_alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
    task_id='slack_failed_alert',
    http_conn_id='slack_connection',
    webhook_token=Variable.get("slackWebhookToken", default_var=""),
    message='@here DAG Failed {}'.format(task_name),
    channel='#epm-marketing-dev',
    username='Airflow_{}'.format(ENVIRONMENT_SUFFIX),
    icon_emoji=':red_circle:',
    link_names=True,
  )
  return failed_alert.execute

task_with_failed_slack_alerts = PythonOperator(
  task_id='task0',
  python_callable=<file to execute>,
  on_failure_callback=slack_failed_task,
  provide_context=True,
  dag=dag)
```

As @Deep Nirmal Note: Make sure you have slack_connection added in your Airflow connections as

```
host=https://hooks.slack.com/services/
```

Comment: this example is not complete. what is meant by "have slack_connection added in your Airflow connections" mean?

Comment: @RaviR have a look under the Airflow Web UI under Admin -> Connections or alternatively navigate to `http://your-airflow-server:8080/admin/connection/`