# Airflow Logs in Slack

Tags: airflow, slack

I would like to know how I can report a log in my Slack message with Airflow.

I have tried to circumvent this issue by saving my exception error in a new function which includes also the original function :

```
def other_fun():
   logf = open("log_original_main.log", "w")
   try:
      original_main()
   except Exception as e:
      logf.write(str(e))
   logf.close()
```

But I have no idea with a Bash Operator.
So I hope you can provide a more general solution which works for both cases.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I would say [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054427/how-to-integrate-apache-airflow-with-slack) helps ("How to integrate Apache Airflow with slack?").

Answer (score 0):

Airflow has an operator for slack notification called "**SlackAPIPostOperator**"

```
SlackAPIPostOperator(
  task_id='Your_TASK_ID',
  token='YOUR_TOKEN',
  text="Message you want to notify in your slack",
  channel=SLACK_CHANNEL,
  username=SLACK_USER)
```

For more information you can visit [Here](https://medium.com/datareply/integrating-slack-alerts-in-airflow-c9dcd155105), it will guide you how to generate token and when and where to use this operator.
 You can also use SlackWebhookOperator check ([for more information](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1801baefe44f361010c23e6ec4ee8b8569eab82d/airflow/contrib/operators/slack_webhook_operator.py#L25))

And also [this answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52054663/8660480)r will help you.