# How to gather input to Airflow from slack

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, slack

I have processes which require manual data QC. The objective is to send a link to the report, for the user to review, and have the process continue if approved. I was hoping it was possible to send a slack message from an airflow task, with an approved/denied button, to interactively mark the task as succeeded/failed.

Comment: You can send content to slack using the [`SlackOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/slack_operator.html) but I'm not exactly sure how you would succeed/fail the task based on user input

Comment: For details on connecting check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054427/how-to-integrate-apache-airflow-with-slack)

Comment: updated link for [SlackOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/operators/slack_operator/index.html?highlight=slack%20operator#module-airflow.operators.slack_operator) since the first comment points to a 404 page